# How to set the user-agent of an HTTP request using Gio?

Tags: python, c, gtk, pygobject, gio

I'm trying to do asynchronous HTTP requests using Gio, and I would like to set up a custom user-agent for my requests, but I can't find anything related.

I'm using PyGObject to access Gio, but I could certainly get away with a C example.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the following as an example https://live.gnome.org/Vala/GIONetworkingSample

You need to add the user agents to the headers of your request. In the above examples, replace :

```
var message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n";
```

With :

```
var message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)\r\n\r\n";
```

The idea is the same in python. Check out the HTTP 1.0 [RFC 1945](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt) (chapter 5, pages 23-25) for details on the HTTP request format. The User-Agent header field is described in setction 10.15.

Comment: Hum thanks, I'm going to play with that, but that means I have to reimplement the whole HTTP request function by hand...

Comment: Implementing the HTTP request by hand is the only method I am aware of with GIO. If you use any other feature of Gio or third party library that makes this easier, you should have posted links to it. Anyhow, the idea is the same: you just need to add a "User-Agent" header to the HTTP request, and any library specifically dealing with HTTP will allow you to do this, in some way or another. If not, then toss it away ;)